# How to earch minimal value in objects array using map() and find() methods?

Tags: javascript, typescript, optimization

#### Task

There is an array of objects of the form:

```
{
  title: 'Macbook Air',
  offers: [
    {
      seller: 'Avic',
      price: 1200
    },
    {
      seller: 'Citrus',
      price: 1600
    }
  ]
}
```

It is necessary to Convert to an array of objects of the form:

```
{
  title: 'Macbook Air',
  bestOffer: {
    name: 'Avic',
    price: 1200
  }
}
```

Where **bestOffer** is an offer with *a minimum price value*.
**Write in one line using *map()* and *find()*.**

### Code

```js
"use_strict";
 
var productList = [
  {
    title: "Product X1",
    offers: [
      {
        seller: "Company X1",
        price: 400
      },
 
      {
        seller: "Company X2",
        price: 200
      },
 
      {
        seller: "Company X3",
        price: 300
      }
    ]
  },
 
  {
    title: "Product Y1",
    offers: [
      {
        seller: "Company Y1",
        price: 1700
      },
 
      {
        seller: "Company Y2",
        price: 1600
      },
 
      {
        seller: "Company Y3",
        price: 1500
      },
 
      {
        seller: "Company Y4",
        price: 1400
      }
    ]
  },
 
  {
    title: "Product Z1",
    offers: [
      {
        seller: "Company Z1",
        price: 50
      },
 
      {
        seller: "Company Z2",
        price: 60
      },
 
      {
        seller: "Company Z3",
        price: 10
      },
 
      {
        seller: "Company Z4",
        price: 90
      },
 
      {
        seller: "Company Z5",
        price: 70
      }
    ]
  }
]; 
 
const destinations = productList.map(item =>
    ({
        title: item.title,
        bestOffer: ({
            name: item.offers[0].seller, // TODO: How to implement find() method????
            price: item.offers[0].price
        })
    })
)
console.log(destinations)
```

My code work for restructuring objects for new array, BUT i dont know how to implement find() method for searching minimal value. Is it possible using find() method in this case??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to find the best offer by price. On each iteration check if the current item's (`o`) price is less than the accumulator's (`r`) price, and take the one with the lowest.

```js
const productList = [{"title":"Product X1","offers":[{"seller":"Company X1","price":400},{"seller":"Company X2","price":200},{"seller":"Company X3","price":300}]},{"title":"Product Y1","offers":[{"seller":"Company Y1","price":1700},{"seller":"Company Y2","price":1600},{"seller":"Company Y3","price":1500},{"seller":"Company Y4","price":1400}]},{"title":"Product Z1","offers":[{"seller":"Company Z1","price":50},{"seller":"Company Z2","price":60},{"seller":"Company Z3","price":10},{"seller":"Company Z4","price":90},{"seller":"Company Z5","price":70}]}]

const findBestOffer = ({ offers = [] }) => offers
  .reduce((r, o) => o.price < r.price ? o : r)

const formatOffer = item => item ? ({
  name: item.seller,
  price: item.price
}) : 'none'

const destinations = productList.map(item => ({
  title: item.title,
  bestOffer: formatOffer(findBestOffer(item))
}))

console.log(destinations)
```

If you need to use `Array.map()` and `Array.find()` - map the array to the price numbers, and get the lowest one using `Math.min()`, and then find the item with that price:

```js
const productList = [{"title":"Product X1","offers":[{"seller":"Company X1","price":400},{"seller":"Company X2","price":200},{"seller":"Company X3","price":300}]},{"title":"Product Y1","offers":[{"seller":"Company Y1","price":1700},{"seller":"Company Y2","price":1600},{"seller":"Company Y3","price":1500},{"seller":"Company Y4","price":1400}]},{"title":"Product Z1","offers":[{"seller":"Company Z1","price":50},{"seller":"Company Z2","price":60},{"seller":"Company Z3","price":10},{"seller":"Company Z4","price":90},{"seller":"Company Z5","price":70}]}]

const findBestOffer = ({ offers = [] }) => {
  const min = Math.min(...offers.map(o => o.price))
  
  return offers.find(o => o.price === min)
}

const formatOffer = item => item ? ({
  name: item.seller,
  price: item.price
}) : 'none'

const destinations = productList.map(item => ({
  title: item.title,
  bestOffer: formatOffer(findBestOffer(item))
}))

console.log(destinations)
```

Comment: Thank U for Reduce, but i have task with map() & find() ussage. Is it possible?

Comment: I've added another solution.

Comment: Wow! Nice! Thank you very much!

Comment: P.s. What is meen `...offers`?

Comment: The `Math.min()` function accepts a list of items `Math.min(10, 5, 4, 3)`, and not an array (the result of map). I'm using the spread syntax to apply convert the array of prices to a list of parameters that `Math.min()` can handle.

Answer (score 0):

Since you prefer to use FIND and MAP, I have a clearer solution for you then.

```js
// product list
const productList = [{"title":"Product X1","offers":[{"seller":"Company X1","price":400},{"seller":"Company X2","price":200},{"seller":"Company X3","price":300}]},{"title":"Product Y1","offers":[{"seller":"Company Y1","price":1700},{"seller":"Company Y2","price":1600},{"seller":"Company Y3","price":1500},{"seller":"Company Y4","price":1400}]},{"title":"Product Z1","offers":[{"seller":"Company Z1","price":50},{"seller":"Company Z2","price":60},{"seller":"Company Z3","price":10},{"seller":"Company Z4","price":90},{"seller":"Company Z5","price":70}]}]



// Search text from Collection
function searchProduct(niddle, haystack){
  const searchResult  = haystack.find(item=> item['title'] === niddle);
  let bestOffer;
  if(searchResult){
    bestOffer = getBestOffer(searchResult);
  }
  return bestOffer; 
}



// Search for best Offer
function getBestOffer(dataInfo){
  let bestOffer = {seller: null,price: null};
  dataInfo['offers'].map((item, index)=>{
    if(bestOffer.price === null || bestOffer.price > item.price){
      bestOffer = item;
    }
  })
  return bestOffer;
}


//run
console.log( searchProduct("Product Z1", productList) );

//output is 
//  Object {seller: "Company Z3", price: 10}
```

I hope you like it.